# How to fetch the count of businesses or premises in an area using Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

I need to be able to guesstimate an area's population density.

For example, if I selected Time's Square, I need to get the rough population density in a 1KM radius.

I know the Places API does not have a specific function for this, but I think something like this could work:

Fetch the count of all the businesses or premises in an area, and compare them to known results. For example, if central Mumbai has a businesses/premises count of 1000, and a rural town area has a businesses/premises count of 10, then it would be fair to say low density is probably < 100, medium density is probably 100 - 700, and high density is over 700. Or something along those lines.

So is there a way to fetch the count of businesses or premises in an area using Google Places API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not currently supported by the Google Maps Platform -- **Places API**.

If you are interested to have this feature, you can file this as feature request in Google's Public Issue Tracker:
https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker

Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development.